# Android Navigation Component - Navigate up opens the same fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment-backstack, android-architecture-navigation

I'm having a problem where when executing

```java
findNavController(R.id.main_nav_host).navigateUp()
```

or

```java
findNavController(R.id.main_nav_host).popBackStack()
```

Instead of going back to the last fragment in the backstack, it reopens/navigates to the same/current fragment.

Can somebody point me in the right direction why this is happening?

Navigation graph:

```xml
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/main_navigation_root"
            app:startDestination="@+id/dest_main">

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/dest_main"
            android:name="com.example.popularmovies.ui.main.views.MainMoviesFragment"
            android:label="@string/home"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_movies">

        <action
                android:id="@+id/action_dest_main_to_dest_movie_details"
                app:destination="@+id/dest_movie_details"
                app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
                app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
                app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
                app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/dest_movie_details"
            android:name="com.example.popularmovies.ui.details.movie.view.MovieDetailsFragment"
            android:label="@string/movie_details"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_movie_details"/>

</navigation>
```

MainActivity layout:

```xml
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/main_nav_host"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/main_navigation"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        initNavUi()
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {

        findNavController(R.id.main_nav_host).popBackStack()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> true
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {

        return findNavController(R.id.main_nav_host).navigateUp()
    }

    override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment> {

        return dispatchingAndroidInjector
    }

    private fun initNavUi() {

        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.main_nav_host)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(R.id.dest_main)
        )

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration)
    }

}
```

Destination home fragment:

```
class MainMoviesFragment : Fragment(), Injectable, MovieViewHolder.MovieClickListener {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    private lateinit var fragmentViewModel: MainMoviesFragmentViewModel

    private lateinit var moviesRv: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var moviesAdapter: MainMoviesAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_movies, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        initViews(view)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        fragmentViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,viewModelFactory).get(MainMoviesFragmentViewModel::class.java)
        fragmentViewModel.start()

        observe()
    }

    override fun onMovieClicked(position: Int) {

        fragmentViewModel.onMovieClicked(position)
    }

    private fun initViews(view: View) {

        moviesRv = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.fragment_main_movies_rv).apply{

            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            setHasFixedSize(true)

            moviesAdapter = MainMoviesAdapter(this@MainMoviesFragment)
            adapter = moviesAdapter
        }
    }

    private fun observe() {

        fragmentViewModel.moviesLiveData.observe(this, Observer { moviesAdapter.submitList(it) })
        fragmentViewModel.onMovieClickedLiveEvent.observe(this, Observer { handleMovieClickedEvent(it) })

    }

    private fun handleMovieClickedEvent(movieModel: MovieModel?){

        val action = MainMoviesFragmentDirections.actionDestMainToDestMovieDetails()
        findNavController().navigate(action)
    }

}
```

Destination target fragment:

```
class MovieDetailsFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: MovieDetailsFragmentViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie_details, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MovieDetailsFragmentViewModel::class.java)
    }

}
```

The project code on GitHub can be found [here](https://github.com/royhenengel/PopularMovies)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `onMovieClickedLiveEvent`, used in your `MainMoviesFragmentViewModel`, is firing every time you go back to your `MainMoviesFragment` since `MutableLiveData` saves the current value. This means that `popBackStack()` works just fine, but then you instantly get navigated back to the detail page (note: you'll still want to remove your code in `onBackPressed()` since right now you can't exit the app by hitting the back button).

It seems like, particularly with the name of the variable, that you should be using the [SingleLiveEvent class](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java), instead of `MutableLiveData` directly, as per [this blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150).

Of course, there's no particular reason to use a LiveData or go through the ViewModel at all in this case. Your `MovieViewHolder` could pass the `MovieModel` directly to `onMovieClicked`, which could call `handleMovieClickedEvent` directly. That would avoid the use of LiveData (which is designed to store **state**, not events) and better model what you actually want to achieve: an event listener.